# Apache doesn't resolve symbolic links in /var/www

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, lamp

I read all other questions and don't solved the problem.
I have a Ubuntu server 21.10 with lamp(Apache 2.4.48)
I made a symboliclink with  ln -s ~/Sviluppo/myWeb /var/www/myWeb
and it is ok.
Then in apache a made this module:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName myWeb
   DocumentRoot /var/www/myWeb/public
    <Directory /var/www/myWeb>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /error.log
    CustomLog /access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And I enabled it with `sudo a2ensite myWeb`.
Then I setted privileges with

```
    sudo chown -R www-data myWeb
```

Now I have a **Forbidden** error: you don't have permission....

But the same configuration worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04 .
It seems that Apache doesn't follow symlink!!! What can I verify?
Bye. Thank you very mutch.

Comment: This may be AppArmor blocking access to the directory, as Apache is limited to resources in `/var/www` only (despite the symbolic link). If you run `sudo systemctl disable apparmor` and restart Apache, are you able to load the page correctly? If so, you may want to modify your AppArmor profile for Apache. It's a good idea to have AppArmor running if this server is connected to the web, so don't leave it off for too long.

Comment: Thank you very mutch for your help. I disabled the apparmor service but it doesn't solved.

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title in this question answer site. The green check mark ✅ is sufficient. You can answer your own question below and mark your answer as the accepted answer with ✅ instead of @Dan s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apache 2.4, the `Order` and `allow` directives have been removed in favour of the `Require` directive.

In your case, you need to change the two lines to the following:

```
Require all granted
```

Even after making that change, make sure that the `www-data` user has read access to the `~/Sviluppo/myWeb` directory if you are still facing a problem.

Apache will also need the execute permission on the parent directories to be able to traverse the path.

```
chmod o+x ~/
chmod o+x ~/Sviluppo
```

*WARNING: Keep in mind that the last two commands give any user on your system access to your home directory. So if this is a shared system, I would recommend having your site's code somewhere outside your home directory and give read/write access to your user and read access to the `www-data` user on that directory.*

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
<Directory /var/www/exams>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and

```
chmod -R 775 ~/Sviluppo
chown -R www-data ~/Sviluppo/mysite
```